# How to prevent rerendring page when a condition is not verified with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a page which contains a paper contained a question and a list of options and a button to redirect to next question.

```
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { dark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { incrementQuestion, IQuestion, questionRequest } from "../../actions/index";
import CheckBoxWrapper from "../../components/common/CheckBoxWrapper";
import ContentQuiz from "../../components/ContentQuiz";
import history from "../../history/history";

interface IProps {
  currentQuestionNumber: number;
  loadingData: boolean;
  questions: IQuestion[];
  questionRequest: () => void;
  incrementQuestion: () => void;
  numberOfQuestions: number;
}

const Quiz = (props: IProps) => {
  const { currentQuestionNumber,
    loadingData,
    questions,
    questionRequest,
    incrementQuestion,
    numberOfQuestions } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    questionRequest();
  });

  const handleNextQuiz = () => {
    if (currentQuestionNumber === numberOfQuestions - 1) {
      history.push("/homepage");
    }
    incrementQuestion();
    history.push("/contentQuiz");
  };

  const currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionNumber];
  return (
    <div>
      {loadingData ? ("Loading ...") : (
        < ContentQuiz
          questionNumber={currentQuestionNumber + 1}
          handleClick={handleNextQuiz} >
          <div>
            <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom> What's the output of </Typography>
            <>
              <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={dark} >
                {currentQuestion.description.replace(";", "\n")}
              </SyntaxHighlighter >
              <form>
                <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="baseline">
                  {currentQuestion.options.map((option: string, index: number) => {
                    const fieldName = `option ${index + 1}`;
                    return (
                      <Grid key={index}>
                        <Field
                          name={fieldName}
                          component={CheckBoxWrapper}
                          label={option}
                        />
                      </Grid>);
                  }
                  )}
                </Grid>
              </form>
            </>
          </div >
        </ContentQuiz >
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const { currentQuestionNumber, loadingData, questions, numberOfQuestions } = state.quiz;

  return {
    currentQuestionNumber,
    loadingData,
    questions,
    numberOfQuestions
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    incrementQuestion: () => dispatch<any>(incrementQuestion()),
    questionRequest: () => dispatch<any>(questionRequest())
  };
};

const QuizContainer = reduxForm<{}, IProps>({
  form: "Answers",
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
})(Quiz);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(QuizContainer);
```

`handleNextQuiz` increment the counter of question number and redirects to the same page to rerender the component (I think that it is not the best idea to redirect to the same on every click of the button and any suggestion to handle that will be welcome).
But I want to check when it's the last question the user should be redirected to another page to validate and submit. However with my code, when testing the components with a list of questions and when I tried to redirect the user to final page. The component rerendred and an error occurs to mention :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

How can I handle this situation in order to not rerender the same page when clicking next button in the last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const handleNextQuiz = () => {
    if (currentQuestionNumber === numberOfQuestions - 1) {
      history.push("/homepage");
    }
    incrementQuestion();
    history.push("/contentQuiz");
  };
```

The above function is not correct, assume the first condition is satisfied, successfully redirected to `/homepage`, the function is not yet over. `incrementQuestion();` is executed and followed by redirect to `/contentQuiz`.

You need to add a `return` statement in the if condition to avoid executing the followed code, OR use `if else`. So basically, there should be only 1 redirect at a time.

```
const handleNextQuiz = () => {
  if (currentQuestionNumber === numberOfQuestions - 1) {
    history.push("/homepage");
  } else {
    incrementQuestion();
    history.push("/contentQuiz");
  }
};
```